# Google Sign-in asking for permission for contacts when i haven't requested it

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin

In my flutter app i have google sign-in implemented however when logging in it asks me for permission for the user contacts. i do not need this permission.
i have the following scope:

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
'email',

 ],
);
```

Please tell me how to get rid of this permission request because if the user clicks deny then he is unable to login.

Answer (score 1):

This was a mistake when implementing Google-Signin.

I declared scopes in multiple widgets. and one of the widgets had other permissions being asked for. once removed. it worked fine and wasn't asking for permission to the users contacts